# Killing of multiple processes error

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Can someone tell me why this sometimes fails:

```
if [ $(pgrep -f agent.jar | wc -l) -gt 1 ]; then
  kill $(pgrep -f agent.jar | grep -v $(pgrep -of agent.jar) | sort -n | uniq | awk '{printf $1" "}');
fi
```

The goal of this portion of code is to:

1. Check if duplicate processes exist. Note how I reference the .jar file instead of java incase other java apps are running
2. If duplicates are detected, it gets the process ids of the most recent duplicates (ie leaving out the original) and attempts to kill the duplicates.

The code works great. It detects the duplicates and kills them, but sometimes it picks up a third process (possibly a grep pid or ps pid) and tries to kill that. I dont know what the random PID its finding is. Its only temporary which is why im guessing its part of the kill line.

Here is an example error

```
/start.sh: line 15: [: 3183: binary operator expected
```

This ultimately ends up throwing this error to the terminal which looks bad. It may be possible to ignore it since its otherwise doing its job, but that would be sloppy and there is the possibility of some other condition breaking the script, so ideally I need to get it fixed.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What's in your line 15?

Comment: kill $(pgrep -f agent.jar | grep -v $(pgrep -of agent.jar) | sort -n | uniq | awk '{printf $1" "}');

Comment: That doesn't look like the one on your line 15. `[` is nowhere there.

Comment: That is line 15. You're not seeing all the code. The other part of code is not applicable. I could comment it out and will not see a change. The line I sent above is indeed line 15.

Answer (score 0):

it fails (sometimes) because in your worst case scenario your getting 3 different list of pids. Query once your pgrep-list and check the pid again with  `ps -p`.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why its even listing the third PID to begin with. It should not be listing that PID period.